# Why the input type changed while call _call_impl in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, openvino

I'm working at converting pytorch model to openvino IR, the nn of my pytorch is vgg16, and the method is faster rcnn, there is a weird problem when I debug the code.

when I run the following code

`fc7 = self.classifier(pool, abc="abc123")`

the pool object is OpenVinoTensor, abc="abc123" is the test parameters for debuging.
And the classifier is defined as following:

> Sequential(
> (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
> (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
> (2): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
> (3): ReLU(inplace=True)

after self.classifier(pool, abc="abc123") is called, it calls torch.nn.Module._call_impl

`def _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)`

then I found the "input" here is '(ReLU_57,)', which is a tuple, I think it should be OpenVinoTensor, as well as "kwargs" is abc="abc123".

What happened after I call classifier?

Answer (score 0):

What happen when you call the classifier depends on what you had programmed the classifier function to do.

You may refer [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/torchvision-transfer-learning-1d4778b807cc) for further understanding.

Plus, this is how a [classifier in PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) works.